# certreq -submit commnd asks to choose one of the 2 Certificate Authorities

Tags: ssl, certificate, ca, csr, certreq

I am using the below ini file:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=TestCN,SERIALNUMBER=TestSN,O=Test,L=Test,C=UK"
Exportable = TRUE
ExportableEncrypted = TRUE
HashAlgorithm = Sha256
KeyLength = 256
MachineKeySet = True
FriendlyName = "TestName"
[RequestAttributes]
CertificateTemplate = "ActualTemplateName"
```

Then I am running the below commands:

```
certreq -new "test.ini" "test.req"
certreq -submit "test.req" "test.cer"
```

Now, in the second command i.e. certreq -submit asks me to choose one of the 2 Certification Authorities.
I have a requirement where there should not be any such popup, it should be provided as part of ini file or certreq -submit command.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me:

certreq -config "CAServerName\CAName" -submit "test.req" "test.cer""

Comment: reopening an old post: could you clarify what CAServerName et CAName exactly stand for with a concrete example ? Like your serveur hostname is `foo`, you would put `CAfoo` or just `foo` ?